# Modifying the query to solve the Problem 2038 in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, unix-timestamp

I have a SQL query:

```
update party set left_time=(next_dose-dose)/power,takeoff=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()+left_time);
```

How can I modify it without using unix time to get the dates further than 2038-01-19?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the UTC time that is left_time seconds from now, just do:

```
utc_timestamp() + interval left_time second
```

But that's not what from_unixtime does; from_unixtime will produce a time in the session's timezone.  If that is what you need, you could naively do

```
current_timestamp() + interval left_time second
```

but that will not produce correct results if there is a daylight savings transition upcoming, so you have to do:

```
convert_tz(utc_timestamp() + interval left_time second, '+00:00', @@SESSION.time_zone)
```

(An example of why you should always just store UTC times and only convert them for display.)  If takeoff is a timestamp type instead of a datetime, you *have* to do this, since it automatically converts to/from the session timezone whenever you read/update it, though it actually stores a utc time.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But now when the date is further that 2038-01-19 then the server gives me an error that the date is wrong. I've tried to play with sql_mode but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: Then you are using a timestamp field, which is limited to that date.  Set your session timezone to whatever it usually will be, and change the column to a datetime type.

Comment: What is your exact update statement and error?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it works fine!